# Clarifying Bernstein-Schröder property for equidecomposition

Tags: group-theory, set-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $Z$. We say that $A \subseteq Z$ is congruent to $B \subseteq Z$ if there exists $g \in G$ such that $g . A = \{g . a : a \in A\} = B$. We say that $A$ is equidecomposable with $B$ if there is a partition of $A$ and a partition of $B$, each into $k$ pieces, so that $A_i$ is congruent to $B_i$ for each $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$. Write $A \sim B$ for equidecomposability of subsets.

I'm trying to prove the following property similar to the Bernstein-Cantor-Schröder theorem.

> Suppose $A \sim B^\prime \subseteq B$ and $B \sim A^\prime \subseteq A$.
>   Then, $A \sim B$.

Here's the argument I came up with.

> Define the map $f_A : A \to B$ such that when given $x \in A$, the map applies the witness corresponding to which partition piece it falls in. Define the map $f_B : B \to A$ similarly.
>   Define $F : P(A) \to P(A)$ by $X \mapsto f_B(B \setminus f_A(A \setminus X))$ and note that $F$ is a monotonically increasing function on subsets of $A$. Applying the Knaster-Tarski theorem, we find fixed point $X \subseteq A$, such that $f_B(B \setminus f_A(A \setminus X)) = X$.

From here I'm not sure how to proceed.

I found a proof of the theorem that starts in the same way, but concludes in way I don't understand:

> Let $X^\prime = A \setminus X$, $Y = f_A(X)$, and $Y^\prime = B \setminus Y$. **Observe that $X = (A \setminus f_B(B)) \cup f_B(f_A(X))$**, so
>   $$
> X^\prime = f_B(B) \cap (A \setminus f_B(f_A(X))) = f_B(B) \setminus f_B(f_A(X)) = f_B(B) \setminus f_B(Y) = f_B(Y^\prime)
> $$
>   We can therefore construct an equidecomposition of $A$ and $B$ by partitioning $A$ into $X$ and $X^\prime$ and then performing $f_A$ on $X$ and $f_B^{-1}$ on $X^\prime$.

I emphasize the step I don't understand. Can someone clarify the observation?

Edit: the proof I found is [here](http://web.mit.edu/andersk/Public/banach-tarski.pdf), on page 6. I adapted it, in particular to use the fixed point theorem rather than construct the fixed point "by hand" using a union. I must have done so incorrectly according to the comments. Here is a screenshot of the proof.

[image: Banach-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem]

Comment: I'm confused by some things here: $A\subseteq X$, right? So what sense does the definition of $X^\prime$ make? Also, $f_A$ by definition has domain $A$, so what is the point behind $f_A(X)$?

Comment: Oops! I had forgotten that the set $G$ is acting on is called $X$, so I named the fixed-point $X$ as well. I've now corrected the beginning of the proof to name to set $G$ acts on as $Z$ instead.

Comment: I think the observation is wrong. Note that $X\subseteq A^\prime$ by its defining property. But the observation says that it also contains everything in $A\setminus A^\prime$. I think there are typos there and what you will be able to show is that $X=A^\prime\setminus f_B[B^\prime]\cup f_B[f_A[X]]$. It should then follow that $X^\prime =A\setminus A^\prime \cup f_B[Y^\prime]$. I'm not sure whether that helps though.

Comment: I've edited the question to include both a link to the original proof as well as a screenshot of the relevant part of the document.

Comment: @bof sorry for not initially including the source. I recognize that the argument is not mine, and fail to see how, especially in this context, my actions constitute plagiarism. I feel that the tone of your comment, and your answer, are unwarranted. We're all adults here, and there's no need to use boldfaced, all-caps when simply asking "What is the source of the proof you found? I think you made a mistake in recopying it" would have sufficed.

Comment: @JacobErrington My sincere apologies.